# Draw a point on a curve or surface; also draw a line in 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to draw a point on a curve or on a surface. For example, I would like to plot the point $(1,1,\sqrt{2})$ with a special color.

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Or the point $(1,\sqrt{3})$ on the curve

```
Plot[{Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

I know how to plot a plane in a 3D plot, but I don't know how to plot a straight line in such a plot. How is it done?

Comment: `Show[
 Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{1, 1, Sqrt@2}, .1]}]`

Comment: `Plot[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, Sqrt@3}]}]`

Answer (score 6):

When adding Graphics or annotations to a Plot, I like to use the Show function. It allows you to join two graphics objects together. You could use something like:

`Show[Plot3D[{Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.05] , Point[{1, 1, Sqrt@2}]}]]`

Of course you can substitute Red for your special color, and use the following to make a sphere instead of a point.

```
Sphere[{1, 1, Sqrt@2}, .2]
```

For the 2D plot, You can use the same Show technique but with Graphics instead of Graphics 3D

`Show[Plot[{Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue],Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05] , Point[{1, Sqrt@3}]}]]`